# why when making a command on bitcoin console does this appear staggered square brackets appear

Tags: transactions

Why when making a command of listunspent ,generate ,listlockunspent etc , Does this appear?  [
].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is in [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html); `[]` is a list containing no items.

Comment: Thankyou,is this because i am not synced yet?

Comment: It just means your wallet contains no UTXOs, whatever the reason. Given comments you've made on other questions, my assumption is simply that you don't have any coins.